# R code for simulation of a of setup for picking tiles from a bag

Tags: r, simulation, probability

The problem is there is box with 5 tiles numbered 1,2,3,4,5. I pick 2 tiles note the numbers and drop the tiles in the bag. And then I pick 2 tiles again and note the numbers. What is probability that there is no overlap between the numbers? Say got 1,4 the first time and then the second time I get 3,5. No overlap. The theoretical result is `3/10`. But this simulation is keeps giving me an answer close to 0.5. Any insights about what I am doing wrong? Could it be sample function in R ?

I make a matrix with all possible pairs you could get with 5 tiles 1,2 1,3 etc and then generate two random numbers which give the row numbers. I assume these are the two draws of numbers and see if they are equal.

```
  set.seed(1234)
  n=10000
  count=0
  t<-cbind(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4),c(2,3,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,5))
  idx<-sample(1:10,2*n,replace=T)
  i<-idx[1:n]
  j<-idx[(n+1):(2*n)]
   for( ii in 1:n) {
   if( (t[i[ii],1] != t[j[ii],1]) && (t[i[ii],2] != t[j[ii],2])) 
  count=count+1
   }
  count/n
 [1] 0.5004
```

Any insights will be helpful. I am sure the theoretical answer is 3/10

Comment: I don't understand the use of `&&` here. I think you should be using `length(intersect(t[i,],t[j,])) > 0` as your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a loop. 10000 observations is not big enough to prevent you from building a `data.frame` with your samples. In the following code, I take `samples` twice and put it in a 10000 rows by 4 column object. I then identify which rows have `duplicated` picks. I then divide by your total number. The `1-` is there because the code counts `duplicateds`. My result is in line with the theoretical number.

```
n <-10000
res <-cbind(t(replicate(n,sample(1:5,2,replace=FALSE))),t(replicate(n,sample(1:5,2,replace=FALSE))))
1-sum(apply(apply(res, 1, duplicated),2,any))/n
#[1] 0.2979
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile since I've used R so apologies if I'm a little rusty. Seems to me you're almost there. The problem is in your if statement within the for loop. You're testing whether the first number in the first pair is different from the first number in the second pair AND the second number in the first pair is different from the second number in the second pair. But you're forgetting about whether the first number in the first pair is different from the second number in the second pair AND the second number in the first pair is different from the first number in the second pair. Here's the full line:

```
if( 
    (t[i[ii],1] != t[j[ii],1]) && 
    (t[i[ii],2] != t[j[ii],2]) && 
    (t[i[ii],1] != t[j[ii],2]) && 
    (t[i[ii],2] != t[j[ii],1]) 
) count=count+1
```

There might be other ways to accomplish this, but this seems to do the trick. I get about 0.3 for the result. And thanks for the opportunity to think about R again.

Comment: I guess my commenting privileges are pretty minimal right now. Just wanted to say that's a very nice answer from P Lapointe. The apply function is one that's worth learning and using. I made a point in my answer to stick with the OP's process to show where it went astray. But if someone is going to do a lot of simulations with R, they would do well to understand P Lapointe's code.